# Puppet - Duplicate declaration for Registry_key

Tags: powershell, registry, puppet

I have a manifest file to add registry keys and values based on facts (works fine).

```
       registry_key { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate':
          ensure => present,
        }

        registry_value { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\TestKey':
         ensure => present,
         type   => dword,
         data   => $test_key_value,
       }
```

I want to add a second file to remove these if required but when i do i get an error

"Duplicate declaration: Registry_key[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate] is already declared"

Not sure how to get around this - if at all? Any advice appreciated. Obviously a puppet novice...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this problem, you would probably use custom or external facts, something like this:

```puppet
$ensure = $facts['include_windows_update_keys']

registry_key { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate':
  ensure => $ensure,
}

registry_value { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\TestKey':
  ensure => $ensure,
  type   => dword,
  data   => $test_key_value,
}
```

As you have discovered, declaring the same resource more than once but with different attributes is not allowed in Puppet.

There is more on custom facts [here](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/custom_facts.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations Alex's suggestion is the way I'd proceed. Usually the best way, to default it in common.yaml and override based on node name or another level in hiera. Depending on your use case, a less straight-forward way is to wrap those blocks in a conditional (if/unless/else) where it's present/absent depending on a boolean set in hiera. Something along the lines of `unless $exclude_from_testkey` or a [case](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_conditional.html) statement. Let me know if you're new to hiera and/or parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

You have resource declarations for specifying that a particular registry key and value should be ensured present on the target node.  If you also have declarations specifying that one or both should be absent, *and Puppet evaluates both sets*, then what are you actually telling Puppet to do?  It cannot comply with both sets of declarations.

Puppet takes an extremely cautious approach to situations like this, which makes sense given its role in managing infrastructure.  In the event that the same resource is declared more than once for the same target, Puppet aborts.  This produces practical difficulties from time to time, but I am confident that it has protected many, many systems from misconfiguration.

The solution is to ensure that your manifest set declares only one set of those declarations for each node.  You could do that by having only one set, and twiddling their `$ensure` parameters dynamically, as @AlexHarvey suggests.  You could also do it by putting the two sets of declarations in different blocks, and selecting between them with conditional statements.  Or you could put them in altogether different classes, and be certain to include just one of them for each node.

But I have to differ with Alex here on the specifics.  I would not typically use a custom fact here, because that gives control over which option is exercised to the client.  Generally speaking, I want *the master* to dictate questions of how various nodes are configured.  For this purpose, it is a pretty common idiom to use a class parameter to control whether the resources are ensured present or absent:

```
class mymodule::windows_update(
  Enum['absent','present'] $ensure = $present,
  $test_key_value
) {
  registry_key { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate':
    ensure => $ensure,
  }

  registry_value { 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\TestKey':
    ensure => $ensure,
    type   => dword,
    data   => $test_key_value,
  }
}
```